# How to include .so shared libraries in a Debian package?

Tags: debian, package, packaging, deb, software-packaging

I am attempting to create a Debian package of an application that includes a Java `.jar` file and some `.so` library files. This application comes from someone else; I am just converting it into a Debian package.

When I run pdebuild I get all the files included in the .deb package *except* the `.so` files. It appears that one of the build steps is filtering out those files.

How can I convince pdebuild to include those `.so` files?

Here is the command I am running:

```
pdebuild --pbuilder cowbuilder --buildresult .. \
         --debbuildopts '-Ibin.exe -izzz' -- \
         --basepath /var/cache/pbuilder/base-wheezy.cow \
         --distribution wheezy --configfile /etc/pbuilder/wheezy
```

The build system is wheezy while the package distribution target is wheezy as well.

Comment: @rekire: A deb file is not a zip file.

Answer (score 0):

You may either create **debian/source/include-binaries** file, listing all your *.so files. Or, use "--include-binaries" option, like described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164621/how-do-i-add-a-binary-file-to-my-existing-ppa-package)